# How to I rotate UIImageView by 90 degrees inside a UIScrollView with correct image size and scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image inside an UIImageView which is within a UIScrollView.  What I want to do is rotate this image 90 degrees so that it is in landscape by default, and set the initial zoom of the image so that the entire image fits into the scrollview and then allow it to be zoomed up to 100% and back down to minimum zoom again.

This is what I have so far:

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);

float minimumScale = scrollView.frame.size.width  / self.imageView.frame.size.width;  
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;  
scrollView.zoomScale = minimumScale;  


scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.imageView.frame.size.height,self.imageView.frame.size.width);
```

The problem is that if I set the transform, nothing shows up in the scrollview.  However if I commented out the transform, everything works except the image is not in the landscape orientation that I want it to be!

If I apply the transform and remove the code that sets the minimumZoomScale and zoomScale properties, then the image shows up in the correct orientation, however with the incorrect zoomScale and seems like the contentSize property isn't set correctly either - since the  doesn't scroll to the edge of the image in the left/right direction, however does top and bottom but much over the edge.

NB: image is being loaded from a URL

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't use a CGAffineTransformRotate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe rotating the image itself fits your needs:

```
 UIImage* rotateUIImage(const UIImage* src, float angleDegrees)  {   
    UIView* rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, src.size.width, src.size.height)];
    float angleRadians = angleDegrees * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
    [rotatedViewBox release];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, angleRadians);

    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-src.size.width / 2, -src.size.height / 2, src.size.width, src.size.height), [src CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I'm giving this a try, it seems to be drawing my imaging in the correct orientation, but it's somewhat squashed and the top / bottom edges cut-off.  I understand that the first part of the code gets what the size of the new rotated image would be in terms of width & height and stores it in rotatedSize. The next bit I see is it defines the context and transforms it - I've been playing around with that part of the code - assuming that's what is causing this squashed image that's cut off either side.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to find bug in my own code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Let me know if you fix the bug, Max - I've been playing with it, still learning so probably take me longer. :)

Comment: well, i've fixed it 7 hours ago :) I've told you to see my edit

Comment: for retina support,     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize,NO,0.f);
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);

Comment: Guys - I'd strongly recommend you DO NOT use this answer. We were using it for a while, and it seemed to work until one took pictures directly with different orientations. In particular, EXIF settings were ignored for non-square images, which can result in the rotated image stretched or compressed to the wrong orientation. I'll add a separate answer which goes into it a bit more.

Comment: This is BAD. Creating a new image instead of changing just the view parameters / transform is essentially wrong. Try doing this for 8mpx images, you'll see.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the easiest way (and thread safe too) is to do:

```
//assume that the image is loaded in landscape mode from disk
UIImage * LandscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed: imgname];
UIImage * PortraitImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: LandscapeImage.CGImage
                                                     scale: 1.0
                                               orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];
```

Comment: problem with that is, that it doesn't rotate image itself, only set Orientation flag. This may cause problems if image is processed by tool that do not read orientation metadata.

Comment: @Marcin, what you say is true, but for those who want to simply rotate the image for display without further processing, this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Any calculations that you do based on the imageView's frame should probably be done before you apply any transformations to it. But I would actually suggest doing those calculations based on the size of the UIImage, not the UIImageView. Then set both the UIImageView's frame and the UIScrollView's contentSize based on that.

Max's suggestion is a good one, although with a larger image it could be a performance killer. Are you displaying this image from your app's resources? If so, why not just rotate the images before you even build the app?

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try as well - images are loaded from a URL (just edited my Q)

Comment: From the UIView class reference: "if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified." Probably applies to your situation.

Comment: Thanks - I went for another solution, which entails leaving the image orientation as it is and instead using the iphone's interface orientation to make it landscape (which is not what I originally wanted - but works out better I think).  I think with some tweaking Max's suggestion would work, and I'm still interested in how I could make it work, should I need to do it in this particular way in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier solution that is also faster, just do this:

```
- (void) imageRotateTapped:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f animations:^()
    {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(self.rotateDegrees += 90.0f));
        self.imageView.frame = self.imageView.superview.bounds; // change this to whatever rect you want
    }];
}
```

When the user is done, you will need to actually create a new rotated image, but that is very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the accepted answer for a while until we noticed that non-square rotations based on images taken directly from the camera seemed stretched (they were rotated as desired, just the frame width/height wasn't adjusted).

Great explanation/post here from Trevor: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

In the end, it was a very simple import of Trevor's code which uses categories to add a `resizedImage:interpoationQuality` method to UIImage. So yeah, user beware, if it still works for you, great. But if it doesn't, I'd take a look at the library instead.