# Objective-C: How to make custom horizontal scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am going to make a custom view like this.
[Please kindly check this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m6EX.jpg)

As you can see, I'd like to make a view in the red circle. I am not sure it can be a tableview or not. 
There should be several selectable items inside that view. This view should be scrollable by touching event to select an item. When an item is clicked, it should move to the center of the screen. Please note: I need to build it programmatically, not using a storyboard or xib.
That's all.
Please help me out!
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017540/how-to-i-rotate-uiimageview-by-90-degrees-inside-a-uiscrollview-with-correct-ima

Comment: http://aspyreapps.com/rotating-a-paged-uiscrollview/

Comment: use UICollectionView for this task it will help

Comment: is there a similar sample library or tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try to use the collectionView.Your function could implementation by it.